# LINQ query. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create LINQ query checking created automatic permissions created in current month. I have list of permissions included pairs employee and company and then I want to get list of permissions created in current month for these couples. Unfortunately it return exception: "Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Exence.CRM.Dto.AutomaticPermissionDto'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context". How can I fix the second query?

```
var automaticPermission = await context.AutomaticPermission
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Select(x => new AutomaticPermissionDto
                    {
                        EmployeeId = x.EmployeeId,
                        CompanyId = x.CompanyId
                    }).ToListAsync();

                var currentlyAutomaticPermissions = await context.Permissions
                        .Where(x => automaticPermission.Select(c => c.EmployeeId).Contains(x.EmployeeId) &&
                                    automaticPermission.Select(c => c.CompanyId).Contains(x.CompanyId) &&
                                    x.IssueDate.Month == DateTime.Today.Month)
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Make separate lists of the employee Ids and company Ids and use those in your query instead.  EF doesn't know how to translate your DTO into SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for `Permissions` that have matching data in `AutomaticPermission`. You can do that more efficiently in one LINQ query, which at the same time will solve your issue:

```
var currentlyAutomaticPermissions = await context.Permissions
        .Where(x => context.AutomaticPermission
                           .Any(at => at.EmployeeId == x.EmployeeId 
                                   && at.CompanyId == x.CompanyId)
                 && x.IssueDate.Month == DateTime.Today.Month)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync();
```

Not only is this more efficient, I also think the match is more accurate, because it matches pairs of `CompanyId` and `EmployeeId`. The original query will find `Permissions` of which `CompanyId` and `EmployeeId` occur in `AutomaticPermission`, but not necessarily as pair.